# WordPress: unable to post new page on school

Tags: wordpress

I'm a teacher and next week I'll be giving a basic WordPress lesson.

I made an exercise for the students and tried to test it today.
Each one of them wil get a small hosting package from my reseller package (neostrada.nl)

The installation goes fine but it goes wrong when posting a new page or post.
Then I always get the message "safari can't find this page", (can't open veylau.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php )

It's very strange because this works on my home network but not on school.
Furthermore, posting pages or posts does work on other hosting providers.

Does anybody know how I could solve this?
Kind regards,
Laurent

Comment: this may be a Firewall issue . that network blocking your site

Comment: And do you know a way to get around this?

Comment: contact you network admin to unblock this .

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem here at work and it has to do with the Firewall blocking it as Cross Site Scripting. Ask your Network admin to check that in the Firewall logs.

Firewall Applience which happened on for us was a WatchGuard.